# How to autofill relatively in excel

Tags: excel, excel-indirect, vba

I've tried to make a VBA, which fills the cells with information. The problem is that I want to define the range relatively. I've made a function which calculates when the autofill process should end. So instead of the range `Range("f3:f5")` the should be `Range("f3:D2")`

I've attached a picture of my spreadsheet which hopefully makes everything much easier to understand.

```
Sub myautofill()
Range("F3").Value = "=R[-1]C+1"
Range("F3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("f3:f5")
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wycvd.png)

Comment: `the should be Range("f3:D2")` - did you mean `F3:F12`? That is to say, F3 to the range input in D2?

Comment: Yes. That was what I meant. But the information about cell F12 should come from cell D2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use D2's content in a variety of ways, like [Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx) or [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

I prefer range, and you might do it like this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("f3:" & Range("D2").Value)
```

The result would be the range from F3 to whatever you have input in D2, which in the case of your screenshot would be F12. Meaning the compiler interprets it like this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("f3:f12")
```